# How can I delete a chapter from a MP4 video?

Tags: ffmpeg

I use Foobar2000 to tag my music.  I just recently found out by dumb luck that it works with mp4 videos as well and shows the tracks as chapters.

One video in particular, it shows it as 19 Chapters, but it should be only 18.  I try to play Chapter 19 and it just throws errors.  Is there a way to just delete this Chapter from the MP4?  I've looked all over and can't seem to get a straight forward answer on how to do it.  I've been using FFMPEG with my video conversions, so if FFMPEG can do the job, that'd be preferable.